# Cohomological criterion for being projectively normal

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, sheaf-cohomology, projective-varieties

Let $X$ be a smooth projective variety over some algebraically closed field $K$ and let $\mathcal{L}$ be a line bundle that is generated by global sections. I want to know whether the ring $\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}H^0(\mathcal{L}^{\otimes n},X)$ is generated as a graded $K$-algebra in degree one. Is it possible to answer this question only knowing the cohomology groups of $\mathcal{L}^{\otimes n}$ for all $n\in\mathbb{Z}$?

Edit: As pointed out in the comments, there cannot be a *characterization* of this property in terms of the dimensions of the cohomology groups. But are there maybe some *sufficient* or *necessary* criteria in terms of (dimensions of) cohomology groups?

Comment: In general, no. Take $=K_X$, the canonical bundle of a genus 2 curve $X$.

Comment: I know that this ring is in general not generated in degree one. The question is whether one can check this property by looking at the cohomology groups.

Comment: What do you mean by knowing the cohomology groups? You mean only the dimensions?

Comment: Yes, I guess I mean the dimensions.

Comment: Then the answer to you question is no. Just consider $K_C$ on a projective smooth curve  $C$ of genus $g\geq 2$. The $h^0(C, mK_C)$ is independent of $C$, but only depends on the genus. But the canonical ring is generated in degree one if and only if $C$ is not hyperelliptic.

Comment: Okay, you are right (although I guess one needs $g>2$ because for $g=2$ it is always hyperelliptic). Are there maybe some sufficient criteria in terms of some cohomology groups vanishing?

Comment: Since $L$ is globally generated, you have a sequence $0 \to M_L \to H^0(X,L)\otimes \mathcal{O}_X \to L \to 0$, which defines a vector bundle $M_L$. The property that you want is implied by $H^1(X,M_L\otimes L^{q}) = 0$ for all $q\geq 1$.